# Show readmore in wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress Twenty Eleven theme how to show read more after one post without writing any `<!--read more-->` in post page

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The a look at [the_excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)

Answer (score 0):

Go wordpress admin panel and click reading under reading, choose summary instead of full text. That will help you.

Dashboard --> Settings --> Reading and click on "Summary" instead of "Full text"

**EDIT:**
The above settings for feeds. for showing in the home page, While you adding post put your cursor where you want to add "more" tag and then click Alt+Shift+T or click the button left to spell checker it will insert a more tag on your posts. I think this might work..

Answer (score 0):

use the_excerpt() function in your post and add filter excerpt_more and add readmore.. link.
here this blog uses same function which is develop by me [Latest smartphone apps][1]

[1]: http://latestsmartphoneapps.com here on index page all post summery is given and readmore.. link is given which then display full post.

If you want such functionality let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for Excerpt.

```
<?php query_posts('cat=ID'.'&showposts=NO. OF POST') ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,65).' [...]'; ?></p>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More...</a>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```